# Lodash _.map method returns unexpected result when array provided instead of iteratee

Tags: javascript, lodash

When I have this array for example:

```
const x = [1, 2, 3]
```

and I try this:

```
_(x).map(x).value()
```

I'm getting this result:

```
[false, false, false]
```

Any reason why this is the output? map expectes to get a callback, and suppose to invoke the callback on each element the array has. I'm passing it an array instead, so what happens here?

Comment: "*Any reason why this is the output?*" garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: I want to understand the logic behind this garbage..

Comment: It's applying `iteratee` to the result. So, it's attempting to match the array against each value in the array. Which is garbage. What else would you expect to happen?

Comment: throw an error as it tries to apply the array on each value in the array. Why the result is false and not undefined for example?

Comment: Because the array `[1, 2, 3]` does not match `1` nor `2` nor `3`. `iteratee` will create a matcher in this case. As is dicusssed in the docs.